# Not able to set CSS attribute after draggable drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are developing a jQuery plugin that creates a DIV with multiple "columns" inside it.  As the user scrolls the DIV, the scroll will "snap" to the column edge.  I have created a jsFiddle which demonstrates this.  Scroll the box to the right until it snaps to the end of column 1.  http://jsfiddle.net/vcYjm/3/

Here's the problem.  As the user drags the scroll handle, we update the scroll position of the columns with this code at the of the *drag* code block:

```
$('.'+snapHolder).css('right', snapScrollPos+'px');
```

That works fine when the page is initially loaded, but once there is any other setting of the position attributes, it stops working.  For example, reload the jsFiddle, then click on the link *"set $('.snapHolder').css('left', '-50px')"*.  The drag will no longer work.  Similarly, if you scroll until the first snap, the scroll no longer works.

Here is the bit of code which fires in the snap zone before the column:

```
if ( colOffset > (colWidth - snapSize) && colOffset < colWidth ) {
        inAfter = false;
        if (!inBefore) {
            inBefore = true;                
            console.log("before");
            $('.'+snapHolder).css('left', '-' + fullWidth*(colNum+1) + 'px');
            $handle.parents(':eq(2)').find('.'+dragHandle).css({'left': leftPosition});
        }
    }
```

and after the column:

```
} else if ( colOffset < snapSize ) {
    inBefore = false;
    if (!inAfter) {
        inAfter = true;
        console.log("after");
        $('.'+snapHolder).css('left', '-' + fullWidth*colNum + 'px');
        $handle.parents(':eq(2)').find('.'+dragHandle).css({'left': leftPosition});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem I noticed. You are using the "right" attribute to set the position of the snapHolder. Yet, your using the "left" attribute as your snap position.

Once you set the "left" attribute, the "right" attribute gets ignored.

So stick with one. Either use left, or right.

You can't use both.

Comment: I had considered that but did indeed change this line to:
$('.'+snapHolder).css('left', snapScrollPos2+'px');
Same thing happens.  In fact, you click the $('.snapHolder').css('left', '-50px') link at the bottom and you will see that it breaks the crolling, with the "right" attribute never having been set.

Comment: You should double check what you are doing, because when I changed all the "left" to "right" it works. http://jsfiddle.net/AJMn7/

Comment: In your fiddle, the scrolling now works but the snapping is broken.  As I said, one setting of a position attribute seems to break a different setting of it.  You've simply switched which setting is working.